# How do I enable HTTPS redirect in Mayan EDMS

Tags: django, mayanedms

I have a session of Mayan in docker with traefik for hosting on the local network. I want to use my keycloak with oidc.

Following [this forum post](https://forum.mayan-edms.com/t/oidc-login-config/212/3) works, but the `redirect_uri` is `http` and not `https`. As is the case with case django project I have tried setting

```
MAYAN_SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER=("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
```

which didn't work and reading the documentation and source code haven't let me to any obvious settings.